# Why got "expected class or object definition" in very simple prog in f#

Tags: f#

very simple grog:

```
printfn "a"
```

got

```
expected class or object definition
```

when using

```
fsc a.fs
```

it seems man always got this using scala.I don't know why.every write this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv=printfn "a"
```

or this:

```
module A

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv=printfn "a"
```

《ExpertF#.4.0》page 172 told me I can do this directly

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, `fsc` is the Scala compiler, not F#.

Given how old Expert F# 4.0 is, I assume it suggested installing mono; in this case, the F# compiler is `fsharpc`.

If you have the dotnet SDK instead, then the F# compiler is not directly available as a command, instead you need to use `dotnet build` with a .fsproj file.

Comment: Thanks!but I use fsc.exe in window.It's the fsharp compiler.I searched the computer,and there is no fsharpc.exe